# What is the difference between 假如 and 例如?

Tags: meaning, difference

What's the difference between 假如 and 例如? As far as I know, their usage is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their usage are quite different.

假如 means "if" or "in case".

例如 means "such as" or "for example".

Answer (score 1):

I would translate 假如 as a "false if." That is, as a "hypothetical." 例如 translates into "if," in the "example" (例) sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

假如 is a condition word, it means "if" (some conditions happen, then...)

例如 is to list a few examples as to what the speaker was talking about earlier, it means "for example"