# Which "if" is appropriate for what situations

Tags: word-choice

As a follow up to ["What is the difference between 假如 and 例如?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/6603/3124) I've become unclear on the use of the if statement in Chinese.

For the most part I would use 如果 as an if statement when ever it's required but I have now stumbled across a few:

```
假如 Jiǎrú - if 
要是 Yàoshi - if
若是 Ruòshì - if
如果 Rúguǒ - if / in case / in the event that
倘 Tǎng - if / supposing / in case
倘若 Tǎngruò - provided that / supposing that / if
假若 Jiǎruò - if / supposing / in case
假使 Jiǎshǐ - if / in case / suppose / given ...
```

Translations from [MDBG](http://www.mdbg.net/)

All these translate into "if" so how are they used differently or are they interchangeable?

Comment: 要是 is also useful, some of the others are more formal.

Answer (score 3):

## 假如 Jiǎrú - if

Generally used. In most case, it's for something that wouldn't happen.

## 要是 Yàoshi - if

Mostly used in `最近雾霾这么厉害，要是我离开北京就好了` - `It'd be great if I had left Beijing! The air pollution is so heavy here.`

## 若是 Ruòshì - if

Literally used, similar to `要是`

## 如果 Rúguǒ - if / in case / in the event that

Generally used.

## 倘 Tǎng - if / supposing / in case

Almost only used in literature works.

## 倘若 Tǎngruò - provided that / supposing that / if

Mostly used in love letters or lyrics.

假若 Jiǎruò - if / supposing / in case

## Seldom used. A bit like `假如`

假使 Jiǎshǐ - if / in case / suppose / given ...

## Seldom used.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much interchangeable, 如果,假如,假使,要是 are more common used ones, as a native speaker, I rarely hear 倘, only saw it in literature books.